# $r=4\sin3\theta$Tangent

Tags: calculus, functions, factoring, tangent-line, rationalising-denominator

I want to find $r =4\sin3\theta$ Tangent.
However, I can't solve into factors of denominator.
what can I do for this?[image]

Comment: By tangent do you mean the derivative?

Comment: Look here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992847/finding-the-equation-of-a-tangent-line-to-a-polar-curve

Comment: yes, derivative

Comment: Ok your derivative is correct, and you can't really simplify further other than taking out a factor of $4$